# Hide PDFs from Google and Smart Search in Kentico

Tags: pdf, media, kentico

Not sure if this is even possible but wanted to give it a shot.

Is it possible to **add PDFs and other files to Kentico Media Library folder that wouldn’t be searchable through Google or another search engine**? It also should not be searchable through Kentico's Smart Search.

Users should be able to access it ONLY in case they know the full URL.

I know I can add the path to robots.txt to disable indexing, but is there are more foolproof way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, any files in the Media Library are not searchable by Kentico's smart search index (you need to add files to the Content Tree to be able to index them, or create a custom indexer yourself).

The robots.txt is the way to go, search engines honor it as long as it's set properly.

If you want to take another step, you would have to modify the Response the server gives for those files and include the headers

X-Robots-Tag: noindex

there are more tags to look at [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag).

You can modify the response tags through the [URL rewrite engine in IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2012/11/02/change-or-modify-a-response-header-value-using-url-rewrite/).

Comment: Thanks Trevor, this is very helpful, I'll test some of these.